# docker, almost there, but undocumented exit code

Tags: docker

Have a docker image which builds without errors.  However, when executing docker-compose up, the below errors are the last few lines of the output and....nothing.  And, what is exit code 4 you ask?  Me too. Docker has no documentation on this error code.  Any ideas from anyone would be great.  I am attempting to containerize a python dash app.

```
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
web_1  | Application object must be callable.
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:22 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_1  | [2021-05-01 02:32:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
analytics_app_web_1 exited with code 4
```

Comment: 'exit code 4' looks like it came from the app, not from docker.  Is analytics_web_app something you wrote?  I imagine the problem is it's not callable (!), which is likely a problem in the python code.  Search for info on callable objects in Python.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for taking the time to review this.  I hadn't thought of looking for python related errors.  On it.